# Boganella quote - what is being said?

Tags: borderlands-the-pre-sequel

In borderlands the pre-sequel, you can obtain a shotgun that talks like a female bogan: https://borderlands.fandom.com/wiki/Boganella

One of its quotes is:

> F**k you in the c**t and the *** and the f**kin's s**m p***e!

I never managed to figure out all the censored parts. So far I managed to "decypher" (I put it spoiler because I do not know how I'm supposed to post profanities):

> Fuck you in the cunt and the ass and the fuckin's ....

Anyone know the full sentence?

Comment: If it helps, you can hear the line in this [video](https://youtu.be/ttUV-bghHp0) at a bit after 45s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm struggling to think of a swear word or any bogan slang that might fit those last two words.

If you listen to the [clip](https://youtu.be/ttUV-bghHp0) it sounds like she might just be saying "same place". The point is, Boganella is tapping into the stereotype of the drunk, unsophisticated, and incoherent "bogan". The gun is voiced by [Elle Dawe](https://m.imdb.com/name/nm3186109/), who had already been playing such a stereotype in Housos for a few years. There's a decent chance that nany of the lines were ad libbed by Dawe, and the game producers simply selected the funniest ones.

As for why two innocent words would be bleeped - it adds to the humour of the line, and makes you think it could be something worse than it really is.

Another example of this phenomenon is the [bleeped Count](https://youtu.be/InZInH0RlL4)

Answer (score 0):

The missing words are

> sperm purse

aka scrotum

Comment: Is there a credible source for this answer?